# Es posible pasar una List<objeto> desde .cs a formulario .aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

soy nuevo en el foro.

Les comento mi problema. Estoy realizando una pagina web en asp.net y necesito pasar, si es posible, un lista de objetos desde la clase del formulario (en este caso Vestidos.aspx.cs) para poder poder usarla en Vestidos.aspx y ahi poder mostrar la lista de objetos que hay en esa lista.
Si la lista la lleno directamente desde Vestidos.aspx me funciona perfecto, pero yo necesito realizar filtros, por eso preferia pasarla directamente. No se si existe la posibilidad de hacerlo y como.

Espero puedan ayudarme, voy a dejar el codigo como para que mas o menos se den una idea.

Gracias de antemano.

```
                                <%List<Articulos> listaArticulos = new List<Articulos>(); %>
                                <%listaArticulos = negArticulos.obtenerArtCategorias(5); %>
                        <%Marcas mar = new Marcas(); %>--%>

                       

                       <%foreach (Articulos art in listaArticulos)
                        { %>
                  

                       <!-- Single Product -->
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="single-product-wrapper">
                                <!-- Product Image -->
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <%--<img src="img/product-img/product-1.jpg" alt=""/>--%>
                                    <img src="img/product-img/product-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    <!-- Hover Thumb -->
                                    <img class="hover-img" src="img/product-img/product-2.jpg" alt=""/>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Product Description -->
                                <div class="product-description">
                                   
                                   <%-- <% int id_marca = art.id_marca; %>--%>
                                   <%-- <% mar = negMarcas.BuscarMarca(id_marca);  %>--%>

                                     <span>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></span>
                                    <br />
                                    <span>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMarca" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></span>
                                    <a href="single-product-details.aspx">
                                        <h6>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h6>
                                    </a>
                                    <p class="product-price">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrecio" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></p>
                                    <!-- Hover Content -->
                                    <div class="hover-content">
                                        <!-- Add to Cart -->
                                        <div class="add-to-cart-btn">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn essence-btn">Add to Cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <%} %>
```

Asi se muestra los objetos en el aspx, cargados directamente ahi.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             List < Articulos > listaArticulos = new List<Articulos>();  
              listaArticulos = negArticulos.obtenerArticulos();

        foreach (Articulos art in listaArticulos)
        {
            lblCodigo.Text = art.codigo_articulo;
            lblMarca.Text = art.id_marca.ToString() ;
            lblNombre.Text = art.nombre_articulo;
            lblPrecio.Text = art.precio_articulo.ToString();
        }

        

    }
```

Y asi lo tenco en el aspx.cs. Claramente aca me muestra el ultimo cargado, por eso quiero enviar la lista completo.

Saludos a todos.

Comment: no entiendo bien que quieres hacer, pero no puedes usar un `ViewBag`?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. La idea es poder mostrar los articulos (es una pagina ecommerce) de la forma que lo trae el template de la pagina, pero tambien poder filtrar por precio y categoria. Yo lo que quiero hacer es cargar desde el .cs la lista con los articulos cargados en la base de datos y pasarla al aspx asi los muestro. No se si me explico, o tal vez estoy haciendo algo que no se puede. Soy bastante nuevo en asp.net. Voy a investigar el viewbag que no lo conozco.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que le entendí la solucion seria con un Repeater, le muestro un pequeño ejemplo de como seria.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repetidor" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>

       
          <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "codigo_articulo") %>></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" runat="server" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nombre_articulo") %>></asp:Label>

       
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

y en el aspx.cs

```
 List<Articulos> listaArticulos = new List<Articulos>();
        listaArticulos = negArticulos.obtenerArticulos();

        Repetidor.DataSource = listaArticulos;
        Repetidor.DataBind();
```

Espero que le sirva.